# Rails: PostGIS error when i run rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, postgis

I have some trouble with postgis. I use rails 4, and I'm on mac osx sierra 10.12.

I have a superuser ekylibre for postgis and I have a file database.yml with this information:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  postgis_extension: []
  schema_search_path: public,postgis
  username: ekylibre
  password: ekylibre
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

When I try to run:

`rake db:create`

I have this error :

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not
>   open extension control file
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.5/9.5.7/share/postgresql@9.5/extension/postgis.control":
>   No such file or directory

I have postgis of course. I used homebrew to install postgis.
Someone have a solution or a track? 
Thank's you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we used postgis adapter, we created postgis extensioin for our databases manually:

```
$ psql -c your_database_name
$ CREATE_EXTENSION postgis
```

and also I'm not sure about theese strings at your `database.yml`

```
postgis_extension: []
schema_search_path: public,postgis
```

I think, you can drop them.